# How to add smoothing to Spark Image from external source

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex-spark

By default images from remote domains are not accessible or smoothed without the remote server adding a policy file. I remember in another project we were able to enable smoothing in these situations. We had to set or add the remote domain to trusted domains array. I don't have this code anymore and I can't remember how we did it. Does someone know what I'm talking about and how to enable it?

**More context**
Add this code to your Flex Application:

```
<s:Image id="myImage" source="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" smooth="true" height="200" width="400" />
```

and run it in the browser. If you run it from file:// it should show the image smoothed. [image]

That's because Flash Builder gives it special permissions during development. If you put it on a server, for example, `http://localhost:8888/Project-debug/Project.html`, you'll see it is not smoothed and errors are shown in the console:

[image]

```
Error: Request for resource at https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png by requestor from http://localhost:8888/Project-debug/Project.swf/[[DYNAMIC]]/3 is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png halted - not permitted from http://localhost:8888/Project-debug/Project.swf
Error: Request for resource at https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png by requestor from http://localhost:8888/Project-debug/Project.swf/[[DYNAMIC]]/3 is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.
```

Answer (score 0):

it should work if you load the image as

```
[Bindable]
var bmp : Bitmap = Bitmap( imgLoader.content );
```

and then apply

```
bmp.smooth = true;
```

, and then use bmp as binding source for your image.